# Divide Two Numbers Using Long Division

Tags: popularity-contest, math, division

Your challenge is to divide two numbers using long division. The method we used to use in old days of school to divide two numbers.

Example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division)
You should **NOT** use `/` or any other division operator in your code.

Also, this is not [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art)

**Example:**

```
Input  : 4 2 (4 divided by 2)  

Output : 2 0 (here 2 is quotient and 0 is remainder)
```

Another example

```
Input  : 7182 15 (7182 divided by 15)  

Output : 478 12 (7170 is quotient and 12 is remainder)
```

The answer with most up-votes after 24 hours wins because this is a popularity contest.

Comment: Even using the hand method I still mentally *divide* each grouping. I guess you could subtract in a loop or multiply by the inverse, but those just seem like trivial workarounds. Also, you might want to give better examples than single-digit numbers if you want the "long-hand" method to show clearly.

Comment: @Geobits is right, everyone still uses division (mostly mentally) even when performing long division. I suggest the modifying the requirement like "division operators may only be used if the result is less than 10". All that long division serves to do is break a large division problem into a bunch of smaller division problems where each quotient is guaranteed to be in the range of 0 through 9.

Comment: please explain the requirement in simple words (sorry, I am not so good at english !)

Comment: In the old days of school, computers were expensive, so we had calculators instead.  I used the fingers on my *hands* to type division calculations into my calculator.  Is this the "hand" method you refer to?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma **NOOO** the one we used ti do by pen/pencil and a paper!

Comment: @ The downvoter, please explain the reason of your down-vote!

Comment: 24 hours is too little time. It is recommended that you wait for a while (maybe a week), and update the winner every now and then.

Comment: The [previous long division of integers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1624/194) question had a spec and required output which made clear what calculations had to be performed. The [long division of polynomials](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/842/194) question would be most easily implemented by long division even if that weren't specified. This one is so imprecise that you're praising answers which don't even pretend to follow what little instruction it gives.

Comment: Aww, too bad it is put on hold just as I finished my answer :)

Comment: Reopen! F#:  
`let d a b = -1+Seq.find((*)b>>(<)a)[1..a]`

Comment: It should have stayed closed if you are going to Accept an answer which does not follow spec and only a short time after re-opening. What a waste.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### C

Not exactly a long division - this answer uses the method used in the *real* old days.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    int *p=calloc(b, sizeof(int));
    int *q=p;
    while(a--) {
        (*p)++;
        if(p-q<b-1) p++;
        else p-=b-1;
    }
    p=q;
    int r=0, i;
    for(i=0; i<b; i++) r+=p[i]-p[b-1];
    printf("%d %d\n", p[b-1], r);
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation:

Suppose you are given `a` number of sheep and you need to split them up into `b` number of groups. The method used here is to assign each sheep into a different group until the total number of groups reaches `b`, then start from the first group again. This repeats until there are no more sheep. Then, the quotient will be the number of sheep in the last group, and the remainder will be the sum of the differences between each group and the last group.

An illustration for `8/3`:

```
       |Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3
-------------------------------------
       | 1      | 2       | 3        // first sheep in group 1, second sheep in group 2, etc
       | 4      | 5       | 6
       | 7      | 8       |
-------------------------------------
total: | 3      | 3       | 2
```

So the quotient is 2 and the remainder is (3-2)+(3-2)=2.

Comment: This one is good!

Comment: Actually i would divide the Sheep into group of size b. If i have less than b sheeps left thats the remainder.

Answer (score 9):

## Bash + coreutils

Forget what you learned in school.  Nobody uses long division.  Its always important to chose the right tool for the job.  [`dd` is known by some as the swiss army knife of the command-line tools](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/dd-as-a-swiss-army-knife), so it really is the right tool for every job!:

```
#!/bin/bash

q=$(dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null ibs=$1 count=1 obs=$2 2>&1 | grep out | cut -d+ -f1)
r=$(( $1 - $(dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=$q count=$2 2>&1 | grep bytes | cut -d' ' -f1) ))
echo $q $r
```

Output:

```
$ ./divide.sh 4 2
2 0
$ ./divide.sh 7182 15
478 12
$
```

---

<sub><sup>Sorry, I know this is a subversive, trolly answer, but I just couldn't resist.  Cue the downvotes...</sup></sub>

Comment: Hurray (and +1) for `dd`!

Answer (score 7):

## C

Long division! At least how a standard computer algorithm might do it, one binary digit (bit) at a time. Handles negatives, too.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define INT_BITS (sizeof(int)*8)

typedef struct div_result div_result;
struct div_result {
    int quotient;
    int remainder;
};

div_result divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
    int negative = (dividend < 0) ^ (divisor < 0);

    if (divisor == 0) {
        result.quotient = dividend < 0 ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
        result.remainder = 0;
        return result;
    }

    if ((dividend == INT_MIN) && (divisor == -1)) {
        result.quotient = INT_MAX;
        result.remainder = 0;
        return result;
    }

    if (dividend < 0) {
        dividend = -dividend;
    }
    if (divisor < 0) {
        divisor = -divisor;
    }

    int quotient = 0, remainder = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int)*8; i++) {
        quotient <<= 1;

        remainder <<= 1;
        remainder += (dividend >> (INT_BITS - 1)) & 1;
        dividend <<= 1;

        if (remainder >= divisor) {
            remainder -= divisor;
            quotient++;
        }
    }

    div_result result;
    if (negative) {
        result.quotient = -quotient;
        result.remainder = -remainder;
    } else {
        result.quotient = quotient;
        result.remainder = remainder;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int dividend, divisor;
    scanf("%i%i", &dividend, &divisor);

    div_result result = divide(dividend, divisor);
    printf("%i %i\r\n", result.quotient, result.remainder);
}
```

It can be seen in action [here](http://ideone.com/IiKDxM). I chose to handle negative results to be symmetrical to positive results, but with both the quotient and remainder negative.

Handling of edge cases is done with best effort. Division by zero returns the integer of highest magnitude with the same sign as the dividend (that's `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX`), and `INT_MIN / -1` returns `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @ The downvoter, a reason would be appreciated!

Comment: This a good answer, and completely within spec as far as I can see.  Downvoters gonna downvote I suppose.  +1 from me though.

Answer (score 6):

### Julia

Here is an entry that not only is free from division but doesn't employ any multiplication either. It does the long division quite literally by using more string manipulation than arithmetic. It also prints out an ASCII version of what the long-division would look like on a sheet of paper (at least the way I learned it)

```
function divide(x,y)
    if y > x
        return 0, x
    end

    x = "$x"
    q = ""
    r = ""

    workings = ""

    for i = 1:length(x)
        r = "$(r)0"
        num = int(r) + int(x[i:i])
        sum = 0
        m = 0
        while sum+y <= num
            m += 1
            sum += y
        end
        r = string(num-sum)
        q = "$q$m"
        ls = length(string(sum))
        workings *= repeat(" ", i-ls) * "-$sum\n"
        workings *= repeat(" ", i+1-ls) * repeat("-", ls) * "\n"
        workings *= repeat(" ", i+1-length(r)) * r * (i >= length(x) ? "" : x[i+1:i+1]) * "\n"
    end

    workings *= repeat(" ", length(x)-length(r)+1) * repeat("=", length(r)) * "\n"

    print(" $x : $y = $(int(q)) R $r\n$workings")
    int(q), int(r)
end
```

Results (the `(q,r)` line at the end is just Julia printing the result of the function call):

```
> divide(5,3)         > divide(4138,17)           > divide(7182,15)

 5 : 3 = 1 R 2         4138 : 17 = 243 R 7         7182 : 15 = 478 R 12
-3                    -0                          -0
 -                     -                           -
 2                     41                          71
 =                    -34                         -60
                       --                          --
(1,2)                   73                         118
                       -68                        -105
                        --                         ---
                         58                         132
                        -51                        -120
                         --                         ---
                          7                          12
                          =                          ==

                      (243,7)                     (478,12)
```

I suppose I could get rid of the remaining arithmetic by using a unary number system, `repeat` and `length` but that feels more like multiplying than not using arithmetic.

Don't even try dividing by zero! (Seriously, who would do long division for that?) Also don't try negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

### Python

```
def divide(a, b):
    q = 0
    while a >= b:
       a -= b
       q += 1
    return (q, a)
```

Comment: This is just the same as the C answer by Kninnug

Comment: Too right you are, I don't know C so I missed that. Have given him an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

## C#

Not exactly golfing, but IMO it's pretty easy to follow. It only uses the `/` operator after it has broken the dividend down into smaller sections. It performs division in the "old" way. For example, for `1907 / 12`, it takes `19` and divides it by `12`, then carries the remainder `7` over, divides `70` (from `707`) by `12`, etc.

```
string divisor = "12";
string dividend = "1907";
string output = "";
do
{
    double dd = Convert.ToDouble(dividend.Substring(0, divisor.Length));
    double dr = Convert.ToDouble(divisor);
    if (dd >= dr)
    {
        string s = (dd / dr).ToString();
        output += s.Substring(0, s.Contains(".") ? s.IndexOf(".") : s.Length);
        dividend = dd % dr + dividend.Substring(divisor.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        double d2 = Convert.ToDouble(dividend.Substring(0, divisor.Length + 1));
        string s = (d2 / dr).ToString();
        output += s.Substring(0, s.Contains(".") ? s.IndexOf(".") : s.Length);
        dividend = d2 % dr + dividend.Substring(divisor.Length + 1);
     }
 } while (Convert.ToDouble(dividend) >= Convert.ToDouble(divisor))
 for (int i = 0; i < dividend.Length - 1; i++ )
     if (dividend[i].ToString() == "0") output += "0";
 dividend = Convert.ToInt32(dividend).ToString();
 Console.WriteLine("result: " + output + " r." + dividend);
```

Answer (score 2):

### D

Horribly roundabout method that has more steps than is probably necessary to divide a number, but there you are.

```d
import std.stdio;
import std.traits : isIntegral, isUnsigned;
import std.conv   : to;

TNum divide( TNum )( TNum dividend, TNum divisor, out TNum remainder ) if( isIntegral!TNum )
{
    TNum quot = 0,
         rem  = dividend,
         prod = divisor,
         t    = 1,
         max  = ( ( TNum.sizeof * 8 ) - 1 ) ^^ 2;

    while( t < max  && prod < rem )
    {
        prod = prod * 2;
        t    = t    * 2;
    }

    while( t >= 1 )
    {
        if( prod <= rem )
        {
            quot = quot + t;
            rem  = rem - prod;
        }

        static if( isUnsigned!TNum )
        {
            prod >>>= 1;
            t    >>>= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            prod >>= 1;
            t    >>= 1;
        }
    }

    remainder = rem;
    return quot;
}

void main( string[] args )
{
    if( args.length < 3 )
        return;

    long dividend  = args[1].to!long;
    long divisor   = args[2].to!long;
    long remainder = 0;
    long result    = divide( dividend, divisor, remainder );

    if( remainder == 0 )
        "%s / %s = %s".writefln( dividend, divisor, result );
    else
        "%s / %s = %s (r %s)".writefln( dividend, divisor, result, remainder );
}
```

Obviously `/` appears in the code, but it's in a string and is just for output. There's no string interpolation in D, so it's not diving anything.

Answer (score 2):

## 64 characters in Ruby

```
def d a,b;x=0;while((x+1)*b<=a);x+=1;end;puts"#{x} #{a-x*b}";end
```

Example:

```
pry(main)> d 31,6
5 1
=> nil
```

Comment: This looks identical to the answers by Kninnug and justinfay? (It's shorter of course)

Comment: Oh... I didn't know we had to have a unique approach. I just wanted to write a super short one.

Comment: No that's fair enough. I was just wondering whether I overlooked something else that sets this answer apart from the other two (except its shortness). Although neither of these three answers technically implements long division. ;)

Comment: Oh, well. It was fun to write either way.

Answer (score 2):

**C 371 with whitespaces**

Includes cases for div by zero and divisor<0. Uses subtraction loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a, b, n, r;
void e(int i, int j){ printf("Output: %d %d\n", i, j); }
void g()
{
    if (scanf_s("%d %d", &a, &b))
    {
        r = 1;
        if (b < 0){ r = -1; b = r*b; }
        if (!b) e(0, 0);
        else{
            if (b>a){
                n = 0;
            }
            else{
                n = 1;
                while ((a -= b) >= b){
                    n++;
                }

            }
            e(r*n, a);
        }
    }
}

int main(){ g();}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Brainfuck

*works only for numbers between 1 and 9*

Do not fit the rules, so I don't expect to win but answers in brainfuck are always awesome.

```
++++++++>,>,<<[>------>------<<-]>[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]++++++++[>>++++++>++++++<<<-]>>>.<.
```

[Based on `divmod` method](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#Divmod_algorithm)

Test it here (and try to change input) : http://ideone.com/9L2yYf

Some tests :

> 74 returns 13
>   82 returns 40
>   92 returns 41

Answer (score 2):

## C

Sorry for the bulky code, I am still a noob. The idea is to grab the first piece of bits from n such that k < bits, then extract each bit of n from that point on and update remainder and quotient along the way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int rightMostBit(unsigned int n){
   unsigned int bitmask=0x1 << 31;
   int position=31;
   while((bitmask & n)==0 && position>=0){
        position-=1;
        bitmask = bitmask>>1;
   }
   return position;
}

unsigned int extractBits(unsigned int n, unsigned int start, unsigned int end){
    unsigned int unitMask=0x1;
    unsigned int mask=unitMask << start;
    for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
        mask= (mask | (mask << 1));
    }
    return  ((mask &  n) >> start);
}

void longDivision(unsigned int n, unsigned int k)
{
      unsigned int q=0;
      unsigned int head=rightMostBit(n);
      int tail=head;
      unsigned int r=extractBits(n,tail,head);
      while(k>r && tail>=0){
            tail-=1;
            r=extractBits(n,tail,head);
      }

      unsigned int pointMask= 0x1 << tail;

      while(pointMask>0) //scan all bits of n
      {
           if(k<= r){ //If k less than r, we can do division
              r-= k ; //subtraction
              q=q << 1; //make space 
              q = q | 0x1;  //add a 1 to quotient
           }else{
                q=q << 1; //make space
                q= q | 0x0; //k > r, so add 0 to quotient
           }
           pointMask=pointMask >> 1;
           if(pointMask!=0){
                if((pointMask & n)){
                     r=((r << 1) | 1);
                }else{
                     r=((r << 1) | 0);
                }
           }
      }
  printf("quotient: %d, remainder: %d \n",q,r);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edited:170 with Excel VBA:**

```
Sub Long_Div(n As Integer, d As Integer)
j = 1
If d <> 0 Then
If (n * d) < 0 Then
j = -1
End If
Do While (Abs(n) >= Abs(d))
n = Abs(n) - Abs(d)
i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox i * j & " " & n
Else:
MsgBox "can't divide by zero"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python

## Advantages:

- Go as Precise as you want or can handle
- Find out the repetitiveness from the quotient
- Fast

Late to the party but here you go:

```
def ManualDivision(Dividend, Divisor, acQPrecision, BreakOnRepetitive):

    Repetitive = False
    RepetitiveIndex = 0
    bcQComplete = False
    acQComplete = False
    bcQ = ''   #before comma Quotient
    acQ = ''   #after comma Quotient
    history = []
    a = 0
    b = 0

    while (not bcQComplete or not acQComplete):
        if not bcQComplete:
            for digit in map(int, str(Dividend)):
                a = int(str(a) + str(digit))
                if a in history:
                    if not Repetitive:
                        Repetitive = True
                        RepetitiveIndex = len(history) - len(bcQ)
                    if BreakOnRepetitive:
                        break
                else:
                    history.append(a)
                if a < Divisor:           
                    b = 0
                    bcQ += '0'
                else:
                    pQ = 0
                    result = a - Divisor
                    while result >= 1:
                        pQ += 1
                        result -= Divisor
                    b = pQ * Divisor
                    bcQ += str(pQ) 
                a -= b
            bcQComplete = True

        if not acQComplete:
            acQPrecision -= 1
            if acQPrecision <= 0:
                acQComplete = True
            a = int(str(a) + str('0'))
            if a in history:
                if not Repetitive:
                    Repetitive = True
                    RepetitiveIndex = len(history) - len(bcQ)
                if BreakOnRepetitive:
                    break
            else:
                history.append(a)
            if a < Divisor:
                b = 0
                acQ += '0'
            else:
                pQ = 0
                result = a - Divisor
                while result >= 1:
                    pQ += 1
                    result -= Divisor
                b = pQ * Divisor
                acQ += str(pQ) 
            a-=b
       return '{0}.{1} \nRepetitive: {2} from position {3} acQ \nHistory:{4}'.format(bcQ, acQ, Repetitive, RepetitiveIndex, history)
```

## Result

```
Quotient = ManualDivision(91,256,100,False) #Dividend = 91, Divisor = 256, precision= 100, breakonrepetitive=False
print(Quotient)
```

> 00.3554687499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
>
> Repetitive: True from position 9 acQ
>
> History:[9, 91, 910, 1420, 1400, 1200, 1760, 2240, 1920, 1280, 2560]

Answer (score 1):

### Python

Using recursion

```
def divide(a, b, q=0):
    if a < b:
        return (q, a)
    return divide(a - b, b, q+1)
```